# root and /home in different partitions

Tags: partitioning, root, home-directory

I installed in my HD, Fedora22 and ubuntu MATE 15.04. I did a 4 partitions. At first I installed Ubuntu with 2 partitions, `/` and `/home`. After that, I rebooted and installed the `Fedora22`, just `/` (root) because I was interested to share the same `/home` for all distributions. I noticed my Fedora22 wasn't using the same `/home` that Ubuntu, but created a `/home` into the partition which I mount just fedora root.

I've deleted everything from my HD and start it over, now 3 partitions, `90Gb` for future use, 50 for ubuntu's root and 350 for `/home`. Now I'm not sure about if the `/home` where I'm saving my files is either the `/home` partition of my installation process or another `/home` created into root partition. How can I know that?

PS.: now I have just Ubuntu, maybe my explanation have been a little confuse. I don't intend to use windows at all, but I'd like to taste others Linux distributions.

Comment: WIth the command `mount` you can see al the mounted filesystems.

Comment: Beware that you not only have to use the same partition to mount at the /home directory, but you will also need to make sure that the usernames and userid is the same across all installations. Also, configuration for user-programs (Gnome, Firefox, Libreoffice etc.) resides in the homedirectory, and this might cause problems if the versions isn't the same on every installation.

Answer (score 0):

It MIGHT be possible to set up as you wish, you will need 3 partitions (/- ubuntu, /-fedora, /home,) plus swap space, usually an additional partition that also could be used for both distros.
  When doing the install of the 1st OS, select manually creating of partitions.
set up your / for this install and the /home partition and swap space. Record the device ID for both /home and swap (ex: /home=/dev/sda# and swap also= /dev/sda#).

when this install finishes, go to a boot and look system over to see if good install. Then, boot from next distro DVD and choose install, ALSO choose manually creating partitions for this install. Set up the / for this second distro and use the previously defined /home and swap partitions for this distro as well. This should allow /home and swap to be used for both distros.

Some other things to consider: use the same fstype for both distros. You may also want to be certain that both distros are using the same boot loader (GRUB?).
    Hope this helps, Craig

Comment: I have Ubuntu and Arch installed on the same BTRFS system (different subvolumes), sharing /boot /home and /root.  It works just fine, with a few tweaks to grub.cfg (for BTRFS issues, not related to sharing /home).

Comment: ... Ubuntu has no grub package installed, so Arch is solely responsible for maintaining the bootloader and Ubuntu won't mess it up at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but here goes:

There are several versions of Disk Truth, kept in different places.

There is the On-Disk Disk Truth, where every disk keeps a pointer in its Master Boot Record (or UEFI's GPT) to a table that describes the start and end and "type" of each partition on the disk. This can be temporarily "obsolete" if some O/S or software has made changes and not yet written them back.

Many partitions (but not all) have a "boot sector" which kicks off loading the Operating system from that partition. See `man -k grub`. `grub` has its version of Disk Truth that it uses to find and boot the selected O/S.

In each booted Operating System's `/etc/fstab` is that system's description of Disk Truth, telling that particular system which disk and which partition to `mount` where (`man mount;man fstab`).

An Operating System booted from a different partition would, of course, have a different `/etc/fstab`, with its own idea of what to mount where.

Use the "Custom Install" option of each distribution (yes, I know it's scary, but you asked for it), and tell it where your `/home` partition is (actually, tell it to mount your Home partition on its `/home`), and, especially tell it NOT to format the partition.

When setting up your `/home` partition, pick a partition "type" that is supported by all your installation candidates.

**WARNING** Altering a partition in any way, while it's mounted by an Operating System leads to Disaster

Comment: I liked your answer because now I 'd pay more attention n these details at installation time (next time, not now). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bother you, but I solved by a really really dummy way. I click on my personal files on desktop (I use ubuntu MATE) and went to System directory and right button clicked to view the free space in /home directory. As I saw almost 350Gb (the partition size) I concluded the /home (directory) is in the /home (partition) instead root.

Thank you for the answers and sorry for the waste time.